# Convert Hexadecimal to Binary in C

Tags: c, binary

I am currently maintaining a code which I inherited from previous developer.
I have to understand one function which convert an ID from Hex to Binay. I can not fully understand his logic behind this. Below is the code,

```
int iHex2Bin(char * pchIn, char * pchOut, int iLen)
{
int i;

memset(pchOut, 0, iLen);

for(i=0; i<iLen; i++)
{
    pchOut[i] = (((unsigned char) *pchIn)-0x30)*16;
    pchIn++;
    pchOut[i] += (((unsigned char) *pchIn)-0x30);

    pchIn++;
}
return(0);
}
```

As the name suggest it converts Hex to Bin. I dont understandly the logic of the function. Can anyone explain it? Thank you.

Thanks for your answers. It is bit clear now. I am also adding the opposite function for more classification,

int iBin2Hex(char * pchIn, char * pchOut, int iLen)
{
    int i;

```
unsigned char chInBuff[256]={0};
char chOutBuff[513]={0};
char chTemp[3]={0};

if(iLen>256)
    return(-2);

memcpy(chInBuff, pchIn, iLen);
for(i=0; i<iLen; i++)
{
    sprintf(chTemp, "%02X", chInBuff[i]);
    strcat(chOutBuff, chTemp);
}

memcpy(pchOut, chOutBuff, iLen*2 + 1);
return(SUCCESS);
```

}

I kind of think that this functions are necessary and name of the function is very confusing. C library function can be used. But code is woking correctly and so I did not make any change. I just need to understand the code if in case needed in the future.

Comment: All numbers in C are binary, so what the code actually does is to convert a hexadecimal ASCII-string to binary. 0x30 being the ASCII code for `'0'`. Except this code doesn't actually work, because it does not support A to F letters. Solution: throw this crap away and use `strtol(str, NULL, 16)` instead.

Comment: @Lundin "throw this crap away" seems a bit premature without knowing the context of its use.  There may be dependencies on what looks to be incorrect legacy behavior, and rewriting the function to do what it seems to say it should do might actually break other things badly.  Yes, it looks like crap, but the crap it produces might be an expected form.  I'd be really careful changing this function without looking at how it's used.  Completely.

Comment: It could be reversing a BCD or simple base16 encoding (using the 16 characters 0123456789:;<=>? ). There is no reason to think it is incorrect (other than the rather misleading name; especially if it is BCD).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the function does exactly what you were told. It takes a string of characters as input, and produces another string of characters as output, but I would hesitate to label the input as "hex". The output is a sequence of signed bytes holding binary values.

Let's look at the core of the code: the expression `(((unsigned char) *pchIn)-0x30)`. This reads a single character and subtracts `0x30` which is the ASCII value for `'0'`. So, this expression correctly converts an ASCII digit into a value from 0 to 9. It doesn't correctly handle any other characters. Specifically, it will **not** produce the correct values 10-15 for characters `'A'` to `'F'`, nor `'a'` to `'f'`. The fact that alternate characters in the input string are multiplied by 16... no, that's not enough to make this hexadecimal.

Essentially what it's doing is taking a (presumably even length) string of bytes
A,B,C,D, ... and converting it to a string of bytes A*16+B, C*16+D, ...

You're far better off using one of the standard library functions to convert a string to an actual binary value (say, an `int`), which is very easy to check, print, and so on... and then converting that binary value to another string in a different format. Consult any manual or online documentation. I believe `strtol` and `ltoa` will do what you need.

Comment: This is because of the ambiguity of the term "binary". Some take it as a string of zeroes and ones, others mean 8-bit data octets as opposed to a hex string. It is not exactly defined.

Answer (score 2):

If the code inside the function is correct, then the function is misnamed. It does look amateurish, but it is conceivable it is intended to read a sequence of ASCII digits (regardless of what the C implementation’s execution character set is) and write [binary-coded decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal).

For example, this routine could serve to read text in ASCII and prepare it for use in financial software that uses binary-coded decimal. (Systems that do not use ASCII are uncommon these days, and systems or applications that use binary-coded decimal are uncommon, but the fact that the code shows signs of both of these is some evidence of intention rather than accident.)

With this in mind, we can interpret the code:

```
for(i=0; i<iLen; i++)
```

This iterates once for each pair of output digits. So the number of digits processed is `2*iLen`, and the number of bytes written is `iLen`.

```
    pchOut[i] = (((unsigned char) *pchIn)-0x30)*16;
```

This takes one character from input and subtracts the ASCII code for “0”. Since the ASCII digits “0” through “9” have consecutive codes, the result is the number represented by the digit, 0 through 9. This number is then multiplied by 16, effectively a left shift, and stored in the current output byte.

```
    pchOut[i] += (((unsigned char) *pchIn)-0x30);
```

This calculates the number represented by the next input character and adds it to the current output byte. The result is the two digits are packed together in one byte, each encoded in four bits. For example, the decimal numeral “74” in input will be encoded as 74<sub>16</sub> (`0x74`), which is 116<sub>10</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others say as wrong, code can use the below to convert  successive pairs of hex characters to a byte

```
// inside the loop
pchOut[i] = strtoul((char[3]){pchIn[0], pchIn[1]}, 0,16);
pchIn += 2;
```

This uses a coumpound literal, available since C99.